# Php doesn't create users in database

Tags: php, mysql

I wrote a code that protects me from sql injections, but now it doesn't even create users. Here is the my code:

```
    <?php
$user = $_GET['username'];
$pass = $_GET['password'];

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "test123";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
function selectInfo($user, $pass){
    global $conn;
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO users (username, password) VALUES (?, ?)");
    $stmt->bind_param("ss", $user, $pass);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->close();
    }
?>
```

i get no error when executing but it doesn't create users that i need.
Sorry for bad code. Im new at this.

Comment: Are you passing username and pasword in url? Its also strange any one can know your password.

Comment: You got no error because you are not looking for it.

Comment: If you want to use $conn in your function, then pass it in as a parameter, try not to use `global` if you can avoid it.

Comment: I use get because i want to use it with c#, but maybe i wont use it.

Comment: Thanks for everyone who answered. I appreciate it :)

Comment: Your code looks valid. So the possible reasons are: you are not Calling the function or your connection failed (you are not looking for it) or your db structure does not match your statement. You should at least check the return value of execute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the real reason is you are not calling the function

either do this

```
  <?php
$user = $_GET['username'];
$pass = $_GET['password'];

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "test123";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
function selectInfo($user, $pass){
    global $conn;
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO users (username, password) VALUES (?, ?)");
    $stmt->bind_param("ss", $user, $pass);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->close();
    }
selectInfo($user, $pass);
?>
```

or

```
<?php
$user = $_GET['username'];
$pass = $_GET['password'];

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "test123";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

    $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO users (username, password) VALUES (?, ?)");
    $stmt->bind_param("ss", $user, $pass);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->close();


?>
```

Comment: "*..not calling the function*" was the catch.

Comment: Well, i can't believe i didn't called the function. Must be so blind :D